# Stripe UI for subscriptions with multiple products

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal, react-stripe

Is there a React Stripe or UI Stripe out-of-the-box solution for upgrading/downgrading subscriptions with multiple products?
The Stripe portal can only handle upgrading and downgrading subscriptions with 1 product. I don't see anything in the React Stripe or other stripe docs any other ways to go about this other than building a custom UI solution.

Tried to use the Stripe portal or Stripe checkout, but neither of them can handle upgrading subscriptions with multiple products.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, they document the limitation [here](https://docs.stripe.com/customer-management#customer-portal-limitations). If there are multiple products, your end customers can only cancel them in the Customer Portal and they can’t update them. Aside from the [Customer Portal](https://docs.stripe.com/customer-management), there is not an out-of-the-box UI like you shared and you would need to create a custom UI on your end to [update the Subscriptions](https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscriptions/update).